# The dropdown list in my html form is only returning null values to mysql database

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

Other parts of the form are working perfectly. Only grade is returning null values.

this is my html code:

```
<body>
    <form action="/out" method="post">
        <label for="grade">Grade:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;&emsp;</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="grade" id="grade" required>
          <option value="N121" selected>N121</option>
          <option value="N134">N134</option>
          <option value="N220">N220</option>
          <option value="N234">N234</option>
          <option value="N326">N326</option>
          <option value="N330">N330</option>
          <option value="N339">N339</option>
          <option value="N375">N375</option>
          <option value="BC2056">BC2056</option>
          <option value="BC2109">BC2109</option>
          <option value="JETCARB300">JETCARB300</option>
        </select><br>
        <label for="TPD">Production Rating (TPD):&emsp;</label>
        <input type="number" name="TPD" step="0.001" placeholder="0.000" required><br>
        <label for="plant_load">Plant Load:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;&emsp;</label>
        <input type="number" name="plant_load" step="0.001" placeholder="0.000" required><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>        
   </form>
</body>
```

python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os
import mysql.connector
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql=MySQL()
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates1')
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] ="root"
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ""
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] ="db"
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = "127.0.0.1"
mysql.init_app(app)
con=mysql.connect()
cursor=con.cursor()
@app.route("/")
def input():
  return render_template("power_advisor1.html")
@app.route("/out", methods=['POST'])
def output():
    grade= request.form.get("grade")
    TPD= request.form.get("TPD")
    plant_load= request.form.get("plant_load")
    cursor.execute("INSERT into input(grade,TPD,plant_load) values(%s,%s,%s)" , (grade, TPD, plant_load))
    con.commit()
    return render_template("output.html")
```

The problem is most probably in the html part

help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[this is the error I get when I use request.form instead of request.form.get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr6LV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the whole code again and ran locally and it works fine for me.However I was not having database schema so I commented that code.
also make sure you and let me know you have `app.run(debug=True)` or not.

```py
@app.route("/out", methods=['POST'])
def output():
    grade= request.form["grade"]
    TPD= request.form["TPD"]
    plant_load= request.form["plant_load"]
    txt1 = "{grade} {TPD} {plant_load}".format(grade = grade, TPD = TPD, plant_load=plant_load)

    # cursor.execute("INSERT into input(grade,TPD,plant_load) values(%s,%s,%s)" , (grade, TPD, plant_load))
    # con.commit()
    return txt1
```

```
<form action="{{ url_for('output') }}" method="post">
        <label for="grade">Grade:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;&emsp;</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="grade" id="grade" required>
            <option value="N121" selected>N121</option>
            <option value="N134">N134</option>
            <option value="N220">N220</option>
            <option value="N234">N234</option>
            <option value="N326">N326</option>
            <option value="N330">N330</option>
            <option value="N339">N339</option>
            <option value="N375">N375</option>
            <option value="BC2056">BC2056</option>
            <option value="BC2109">BC2109</option>
            <option value="JETCARB300">JETCARB300</option>
        </select><br>
        <label for="TPD">Production Rating (TPD):&emsp;</label>
        <input type="number" name="TPD" step="0.001" placeholder="0.000" required><br>
        <label for="plant_load">Plant Load:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;&emsp;</label>
        <input type="number" name="plant_load" step="0.001" placeholder="0.000" required><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>        
    </form>
```

Comment: change form action="/out" to action="{{ url_for('output') }}"

Comment: I wrote the whole thing again in my system and it works out fine but check it out and let me know

Comment: It continues to give the same error. Grade is of type string and the rest are float, if that helps.

Comment: can you please send the whole screenshot of the error